# Oracle sequnce unsync sequence violating uniques

Tags: oracle

I have oracle table

```
CREATE TABLE TestTable
( 
    order_number number NOT NULL,
    customer_name varchar2(50) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT Order_Primary_key PRIMARY KEY (order_number)
);
```

and procedure that insert data

```
CREATE PROCEDURE TestProcedure(customerName VARCHAR2) AS
    orderNumber number;
BEGIN
    select testSequnce.nextval into orderNumber from dual;
    insert into TestTable(order_number, customer_name) values(orderNumber,customerName);
END;
```

Lets assume that different users is working with the same table.
One user invoked procedure and inserted data:

```
100 First
101 First
102 First
103 First
```

Second invoked procedure and started insert

```
98 Second
99 Second
100 - Uniques violation.
```

How to deal with that? Put additional constrain on nextval? It should be bigger than id that already present in table?

Update.

```
EXECUTE TestProcedure('data');
ALTER SEQUENCE testSequnce INCREMENT by -2;
select testSequnce.nextval from dual;
ALTER SEQUENCE testSequnce INCREMENT by 1;
EXECUTE TestProcedure('data');
EXECUTE TestProcedure('data');
```

And then it would throw unique constraint (%s.%s) violated. Looks like it is not generate unique value.

Comment: Sequences are just used to handle that. If 100 is already used, a new call to the sequence nextVal will not give 100, no matter the user, client, session...

Comment: One of your users isn't using the sequence to insert into the table. You should have your privileges so your users can only execute this procedure but not directly insert into the table. As a side, there's no need to select the `nextval from dual`, you can use it directly in pl/sql.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are running:

```
EXECUTE TestProcedure('data');
ALTER SEQUENCE testSequnce INCREMENT by -2;
select testSequnce.nextval from dual;
ALTER SEQUENCE testSequnce INCREMENT by 1;
EXECUTE TestProcedure('data');
EXECUTE TestProcedure('data');
```

it is no wonder that you're experiencing constraint violations.

If you change the increment to a negative value, the sequence will now return increasingly lower numbers, regardless of the fact that it has previously given that value.

You have asked the sequence to do that, it's not a bug, it's not a problem with the sequence, it's a problem with what you did to the sequence.

Don't alter the sequence to increment with a negative number, and you won't end up with constraint violations on your primary key (assuming, of course, that everyone is using that sequence to insert into the primary key column).